# Random background image for each div with the same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, random

I would like to apply random background to each div with an `.item` class.

I tried to do this with PHP and CSS, something like this:

```
<?php
$bg = array('bg1.jpg', 'bg2.jpg', 'bg3.jpg', 'bg4.jpg', 'bg5.jpg' );
$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
?>

.item {
  background: url(example.com/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>);
}
```

It works, but every div has exactly the same background image (for example bg3.jpg), and I would like each individual div to have different random background (I don't mind if they repeat once in a while).

I tried this:

```
.item {
background: url(<?php echo "example.com/images/bg".rand(1, 5).".jpg"; ?>)
```

with the same result.

I suppose I need to use JavaScript (which I have absolutely no experience with) to achieve that. I found a working solution for random background color:
http://jsfiddle.net/VXG36/1/

I would like to do exactly the same thing, but with background images.

Comment: If all `div` elements are using the same class and you set the `backgrond` property of this class your background will be set for all div elements. Maybe you want to use different classes or give your elements an individual ID?

Comment: @BenjaminJ. You don't have to set the `background-image` on the class. OP says he wants to have all `div.item` elements to have a random background, so you just need to affect those elements. You don't need to set the image in a class style rule.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Yeah I know that. This is what my comment means.

Comment: @BenjaminJ. That's not at all what it sound like. It sounds like you didn't understand what is being asked for. Individual classes and/or `id`s are not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add any image URLs to the array. The more images you add, the less chance for repetition.

See comments inline below for explanations:

```js
// Set up your array with the URLs of the background images you'll want:
var randomImagess = [
 "http://laoblogger.com/images/image-of-smiley-face-6.jpg",
 "http://images.clipartpanda.com/smiley-face-clip-art-RcGG8gecL.jpeg",
 "http://images.clipartpanda.com/smiley-face-thumbs-up-thank-you-10_smiley_face.jpg",
 "https://clipartion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/green-smiley-face-images-stock-free-green-830x830.jpg",
 "https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/cartoon-smile-samuel-smiles-smiley-face-team_121-67198.jpg",
 "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/ed/e7/08/ede7084f513353a377a4e841d7ba90ed--smiley-face-images-smiley-faces.jpg",
 "https://cdn.schoolstickers.com/products/en/819/GREEN-SMILE-00.png",
 "https://buildahead.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/happy-emoji-smaller-300x300.png",
 "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/85/7d/22/857d22615fd70ccbfa10afdffff0eb1b--mad-face-smiley-faces.jpg"
];
    
// Get all the div elements with the item class into a collection
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.item");

// Convert the collection into an array so that we can loop with .forEach
var divArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs);

//Loop over the array...
divArray.forEach(function(div) {
  // Get a random number from 0 to the highest index in the array
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImagess.length);
  // Set the backgroundImage property to the random URL
  div.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + randomImagess[randomNum] + ")";
});
```

```css
div.item {
  /* These styles are just for making sure the demo fits in the preview area. */
  width:175px;
  height:175px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid black;
  
  /* Use background-size:contain to fit the entire image into the div's space. This 
     wil make the image zoom in/out as needed to completely fit.
     Or, use background-size:cover to scale the image to fit the space of the div. */
  background-size:cover; 
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Div 1</div>
<div class="item">Div 2</div>
<div class="item">Div 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I meant. However, it doesn't work for me... I put the code in head, inside <script></script>. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Barcin Make sure that your `script` is in the file just before the close of the `body` tag. If you put it in the `head` it will search for the `div` elements before they are parsed into memory. By placing the script just before the close of the `body`, all the other HTML elements have already been added to memory and will be able to be found by the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just encapsulate your php code into a function and then use inline style for each div, because regarding less where you repeated the class definition, the last one definition who will work only.

For eaxmple:

```
    <?php
    function randImage(){
       $bg = array('bg1.jpg', 'bg2.jpg', 'bg3.jpg', 'bg4.jpg', 'bg5.jpg' );
       $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);
       $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
       return $selectedBg;
    }

    ?>
    <div style="background: url(example.com/images/bg<?php echo randImage(); ?>)">Div 1</div>
    <div style="background: url(example.com/images/bg<?php echo randImage(); ?>)">Div 2</div>
<div style="background: url(example.com/images/bg<?php echo randImage(); ?>)">Div 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but these divs are automatically generated by a plugin, and I can't style them individualy (or, if I could, I don't want to because there's gonna be a lot of them). Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Barcin so the suitable solution for you is using client-side solution i.e JavaScript such as Scott's solution.